# The opposite of "lenten"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the opposite of lenten?

I need some expression for not lenten cookies, is there some?

Comment: What do you mean by this exactly? That they contain meat, eggs or dairy?

Comment: @sumelic yes, exactly, is there expression for that kind of cookies?

Comment: Indulgent, decadent... positively *sinful* cookies.

Comment: *[Lenten](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lenten)* refers to the Christian season of *[Lent](http://www.catholic.org/clife/lent/faq.php)*, which has many aspects— a time of preparation, of sacrifice, of remembrance, etc. There are innumerable ways various traditions observe Lent. It is therefore impossible to identify an "opposite" for *Lenten* unless you specify which quality of *Lent* you are referring to. Even restricting it to the liturgical calendar in western Catholicism, Lent could be the "opposite" of Easter or of Ordinary Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing about this is that you're not going to find a single word.  A "Lenten" cookie would be one that meets special conditions that set it apart; anything that doesn't meet those conditions would simply be called "non-Lenten" in those cases where you'd need to draw attention to that fact.  Just like you don't have a special word for cookies that don't contain chocolate, for instance.

Comment: word for 'cookie that does not contain chocolate' - worthless, inedible, excrescence.